# Create role specific user for viewing / using Snowflake dashboard

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, user-roles

I'm new using Snowflake and I wanted to know if it was possible to create custom roles / users for only viewing and using snowflake dashboards, so no access to the databases, tables and other features.

Some context, I'm building a dashboard showing some logs, stats and metrics regarding running applications I have a role allowing to use all features of snowflake and want to create roles / users to only access the dashboard and it's features.

So I wanted to know if there is already some predefinid roles or privileges for that otherwise the best practices for it.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had an answer on the snowflake community : https://community.snowflake.com/s/question/0D5Do00000CF3gJKAT/create-custom-roles-privileges-for-the-use-of-dashboards

So I created a role in Snowflake:

- DashboardAdmin (granted select on the concerned objects)

DashboardAdmin is used to create and share (using the sharing dashboard feature "view only") to other users with the role and can view the dashboard without being able to edit it and the requests.

[image]

And only the owner of the dashboard can edit it